# Error while trying to create ReplicaSet on Kubernetes with YAML

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I'm a beginner with Kubernetes and YAML.
I've been trying to deploy a ReplicaSet with YAML.
This is the file for the ReplicaSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata: 
  name: myapp-replicaset
  label:
   app: myapp
spec:
  selector:
     matchlabels: 
      env: production
      name: nginx
replicas: 3
template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        env: production
        name: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

And this is the Pod file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: production
    name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

However, when I execute the *kubectl create -f replicaset.yml* command, I get the following error:
*The ReplicaSet "myapp-replicaset" is invalid:*

- spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string(nil), MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: empty selector is invalid for deployment
- spec.template.spec.containers: Required value

Comment: (You don't usually directly use ReplicaSets or create Pods; instead you'd typically create a Deployment, which internally will create a ReplicaSet, which will create some number of Pods.  That won't directly address your issue though.)

Comment: oh ok that's insightful, I'm just doing this cause this was a practice module in a course I'm taking.

Answer (score 1):

Your `replicaset.yaml` indentation seems to be wrong + with some typos.
`replicas` & `template` should be inside the `spec` level. Also, check the marked & corrected typos in `labels` & `matchLabels`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata: 
  name: myapp-replicaset
  labels: # labels
   app: myapp
spec:
  selector:
     matchLabels: # matchLabels
      env: production
      name: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
      metadata:
        name: nginx
        labels:
          env: production
          name: nginx
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I'm still facing the same errors.

Comment: I just tested the `yaml`, seems to be working fine. Please, make sure that it's indented properly. If it still doesn't work, feel free to share the updated `yaml` file.

Comment: I just copy-pasted the same file that you provided, unfortunately, it's still showing the same error, could it be that this is due to some bug in my system?